# How to treat <iframe> as a normal object?

Tags: html, css

I have a header that also include dropdown on the file "header.html" with the size 1024x180px. As I would like to use this header for many of the pages later on, I would like to have the header on a separate file and import it later.

Now, in a webpage, I import my header by iframe like this`<iframe style="border-width:0px; width: 1024px; height: 180px"src="common/header.html"></iframe>`. I try to set iframe with the size of the header (1024x180). This is enough in the normal circumstance when there is no dropdown. However, when the dropdown is appeared, it is obvious that there is not enough space, and thus, the iframe put the scrolling to see the additional dropping information

I have tried to add the properties overflow:visible in style but it seems to not working add all. In fact, all of overflow properties are not working as no matter what settings it is set (as still require scrolling to see additional contents). The common setting "scrolling= no" is not solved either, as it just simply turn off the scrolling.

Of course, I can set the height to a big number to compensate the height need if there is a dropdown, but that also leave a lot of space reserved for it. What I want is that while in normal case, the header is not overlap with other object but if there is a dropdown, it is acceptable that it overlaps with other element below. This is possible if the header is written in the current HTML file, but not by iframe import currently. And lastly, I don't want to change position of other HTML element, as I don't want to carry to much settings to multiple pages.

My question is how to treat the iframe as it is was a normal object (or in my case a normal header)? If it is not possible, what is other kind of imports I can use (that only involve HTML, or at most, JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for could be achieved with an iframe, but you shouldn't. As I understand you would like to create one header file as an html file and then copy that to every page. One of the problem is, as you found out, that iframes cannot overflow. That means that anything that needs to "pop over" the iframe should be included in de parent html page and the iframe should send javascript instructions to the parent as to which pop over should be opened/closed.

It would be much better to solve this server-side. For example, in php you could create a `header.php` file and for every template file (say `shop.php`, `home.php`) you just include the header file at the top like so:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Have you heard of the `<base>` tag? Put it in the document of an iframe and click on a link from that document. `<base target="_parent">`

Comment: @Chloe Anderson: thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer. So basically, yes, you can open hyperlinks in the parent, but stil no popover that is anywhere near handy to use as a header menu.